# How to access the ressources stored in a JAR that is part of an Android project?

Tags: java, android, xml, jar

I have a JAR which contains a bunch of java classes and some config xml files. I included this JAR in my Android app and I can call most classes of the JAR.

The problem: 
One class that needs the xml config file to initialize is causing an error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException ./Config.xml (file not found exception)

There is no path issue when I run this JAR on my PC. Only when I use this JAR as part of my Android app.

Looks like only class files of the JAR are visible once the JAR is included in an Android app... is it always so? Or is there a way to use ressources files (xml, txt, ...) as well?

Thanks very much for any help on this,

**EDIT**: To clarify what I am doing.
In a class of the JAR I have this:

```
public static final String CONFIG_FILE = "./Config.xml";
...
mFile = new File(CONFIG_FILE);
```

Comment: Need to access from CLASSPATH as input stream, not using the file system.

Comment: Anyhing included in jar shlould be accessible like its a part of your project not even packed in jar if jar is compiled and connected in the right way. res folder with its drawables and other resources are accessible for sure

Comment: Are you trying to access the resources directly from the Android project or does the JAR contain some kind of image getter? Once you compact a Java project into a JAR individual resources aren't accessible (because it's precompiled) though they are still in the JAR.

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to access this.

Comment: @Embattled Swag: Thx. I try to open the xml file from a class that's within the JAR. So both, xml and the class are in the JAR.

Comment: @Stan: Is what you mention valid for API 10? Or is it true only for much more recent versions of Android? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot access APK components as literal files, unless you process the zip file structure of the containing APK file itself.  Typically, you store the components of interest in one of the ways Android knows how to deal with and provides APIs for accessing - assets, resources, etc.

Comment: Is what you mention valid for API 10? even for older API levels, yes.